# store each loop value in a table lua

Tags: for-loop, lua, store

Is there a way to store the loop result in a table in lua?

I tried the following but it does not work

```
 Name = "x-"
    tabl = {}
    for i =1, 5 do
      tabl = {i}

    end
print (tabl[1])
```

Comment: Start with reading "Programming in Lua" book - best Lua tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These questions are due to lack of basic syntax understading, I would highly recommend reading this tutorial: [Lua Tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/lua/)

```
local tabl = {}
    for i =1, 5 do
      table.insert(tabl, i)
      -- or simple way to create an indexed array
      -- tabl[i] = i
    end
print(table.unpack(tabl))
```